# How to create a create a generic class in Java but limit what types you can use?

Tags: java, generics

I want a Fraction class that I can use to encapsulate data and logic regarding fractions, but I want to give the user the choice of what size integer they would like to use. Unfortunately, there is no common super class that covers only these classes: `BigInteger, Long, Integer, Short`

I would use `Number`, but I don't want to allow non-integer numbers like floats or decimals.

Can I do something like this?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Fraction<T> {

    private T numerator;
    private T denominator;

    Fraction(T numerator, T denominator) {
        if (!(T == BigInteger.class || T == Long.class || T == Integer.class || T == Short.class)) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

}
```

The error I'm currently getting is `T cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: Have you tried `public class Fraction<T extends Number>`? That being said, you really should read up on java generics.

Comment: @bradimus - I think the OP's point is that that would allow a `Fraction<Float>`, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Regarding your class check in the constructor: *The error I'm currently getting is `T cannot be resolved to a variable`* --- Use `numerator.getClass()` instead of `T`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I would do is just have `Fraction<T extends Number>`, but have only private constructors and all public methods that return an instance be specific to one of those types. (So, in theory, you could refer to `Fraction<Float>`, but it's only actually possible to get instances of `Fraction` that refer to integer-based types.)

Comment: It probably should be mentioned that the public methods would be public **static** methods—also known as factory methods.

Comment: After realizing that I can't even compare Numbers to 0 (what the heck, Java??) I think I'm giving up on this. Thanks for the response though, I'll give you the accepted response.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a check in your constructor like

```
if (numerator.doubleValue() / numerator.longValue() != 1)
{

    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

check both passed in numbers this way.
this however would allow you to pass in something like 10.0, but IMHO, that's ok.